# How to use variable in two different class methods?

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I have the following code:

```
<?php
class my_class{

  private static $var;

  function __construct(){
    add_action('save_post',array($this,'func_a'));
    add_action('wp',array($this,'func_b'));
  }

  function func_a($post_id){
    $this->var[] = $post_id;
  }

  function func_b(){
    var_dump($this->var);
  }

}

$class = new my_class();
```

What I am trying to do is: on save - add the post id to an array after some checks. Then when loading any page or post use that array of post ids to do some other checks.  When I am saving a post, the variable is updated as expected. The problem is when calling the var_dump on the variable on any page it returns 'NULL'.
It looks like I am missing something, can someone help me?

Comment: Values of any variables in PHP are only kept as long a the script is running. If you load a new page the whole process starts from scratch, with no values kept from the previous page load. You probably need to look into sessions:  http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Please use below it will help you.

```
class my_class{

 private $var = array();
 private $final_val, $saved_val;

 function __construct(){
   add_action('save_post',array($this,'func_a'));
   add_action('wp',array($this,'func_b'));
 }

 function func_a($post_id){
   global $post;
   if( get_option( 'class_option' ) ){
    $this->saved_val = explode(",", get_option( 'class_option' ));
    foreach ($this->saved_val as $key => $value) {
        $this->var[] = $value;
    }
 }
$this->var[] = $post->ID;
$this->final_val = implode(",", $this->var);
update_option( 'class_option', $this->final_val );
}

function func_b(){
 var_dump(get_option( 'class_option' ));
}

}
$class = new my_class();
```